# Bose-Einstein probability distribution does not integrate to one?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory

The Bose-Einstein probability distribution (see below from *Statistical Optics*, Goodman) for $K=0$ is simply $P = \frac{1}{1+\bar K}$.  But this does not integrate to one as all PDFs should. The integral from Zero to Inf does not converge so it cannot be normalized? Is this the correct distribution function (PDF)?

> $$
> P(K)
> =
> \frac{1}{1+\bar K}
> \left(\frac{\bar K}{1+\bar K}\right)^K
> \tag{9.2-15}
> $$
> is obtained. This probability distribution is called the *Bose-Einstein* distribution (or, in statistics, the *geometric* distribution), and it plays an extremely important role in the statistical physics of indistinguishable particles (bosons).

Comment: Please edit your question to use [Mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for equations and text for text.  Those are the site standards and questions not respecting those standards often get downvoted.  We actively discourage the use of images of text and equations.

Answer (score 2):

The smooth BE distribution does not apply to the lowest state. That has to be taken out and counted separately, as the assumption that the energy spectrum of the states can be treated as a continuum breaks down.  At sensible temperatures this state is unoccupied so it doesn't matter.  At low temperatures the occupancy of the lowest state becomes significant and it does. This is the Bose-Einstein condensation.

Comment: Reference for this statement?

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Even the higher order "states" of this distribution cannot be normalized, it appears.  The integrals of P(0), P(1), etc do not converge.  This distribution is related to counting (incoherent) thermal photons, instead of the Poisson distribution which applies to (coherent) laser photons.  So I am still confused by this distribution as it doesn't seem to normalize.